# how to use rewirecond for exclusion a special page from rewrite rule in htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use the below rule in my MVC project for redirecting everything to my `index.php`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But I want to exclude some pages from this rule, how can I do this?

For example I don't want the below page to redirect:

```
http://www.my_domian/public/checkeditor/kcfinder/browse.php?opener=ckeditor&type=images&CKEditor=des&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=fa
```

Comment: Start by posting your complete `.htaccess` as you have it otherwise it would be hard for or to know what may or may not conflict with your current rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a negative condition before this `RewriteRule`:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/public/checkeditor/kcfinder/browse\.php\?opener=ckeditor&type=images&CKEditor=des&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=fa [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Also I have added 2 conditions to avoid routing for real files and directories.

Comment: +1 Or perhaps just use a if folder/file don't exists redirect?

Comment: Thanks @Prix: I added 2 conditions as well.

Comment: if `browse.php` exists you might not even need the 3rd condition :P but better safe than sorry, people hardly provide enough information to us :/

Comment: Very true, 3rd `RewriteCond` may not be needed but I will leave it in case OP needs it.